# Can 20.04 hibernate?

Tags: 20.04, hibernate

I just did a fresh installation of 20.04. I could never get hibernation to work on my last 19.04 install (Lenovo T-580) - should I expect anything different on 20.04?

I have exactly as much swap space as I've RAM (16 GB). I've tried both systemctl hibernate and pm-hibernate; they both seem to actually hibernate the computer, but when I boot again, all my programs are closed.

Is it too much to expect it to work now?

Comment: The hibernation feature is disabled by default since the release of [Ubuntu 12.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop/UbuntuDesktop-12.04#PrecisePangolin.2FReleaseNotes.2FCommonInfrastructure.2FCommonInfrastructure-12.04.Common_Infrastructure).

Comment: I know that. I would like to enable it. I tried, and it doesn't work. So my question is: Is it reasonable to expect Ubuntu 20.04 to be able to hibernate, if I enable it?

Comment: This is an user supported site. We are users like you. The question you are asking has no answer based on user knowledge. Hibernate has worked on my laptop made in 2013 with 16.04, and 18.04. It is perfectly reasonable for me to expect it will work with 20.04. I have not upgraded it yet. Hibernate works on some hardware and does not work on others. Speculative and opinion based questions are off-topic here.

Comment: print the output of `cat /sys/power/state`

Comment: `freeze mem disk`